# Gparted has a little key icon on my Ubuntu partition so I can not resize it

Tags: partitioning, windows-7, gparted

How can I make separate partition (to install windows 7) using ubuntu.
I tried to use Gparted but there is a little key icon on my ubuntu partition therefore i cant make a new partition.

Comment: Is the lock icon still present if you boot from a livecd and run gparted?

Comment: You can't change the the Ubuntu partition while it is running. Boot from an Ubuntu Live USB/DVD and choose the Try Ubuntu option. Then use Gparted.

Comment: If a partition for Windows it must be a primary NTFS partition with the boot flag. Do not create a logical as it will not work.

Answer (score 13):

That key icon indicates that the partition you are trying to modify is currently under use. In order to modify that/those partition/s you have to boot up from a live CD. Then you will be able to modify those partitions. But, be sure to backup your data as it can lead to data loss. But this case is very rare.

Answer (score 2):

If you've booted from a live USB/CD and still see the key icon, check if you have mounted the partition. That could have easily been done if you clicked one of the drive icons from the desktop to check to see what was on the drives.

Unmount those drives by rick clicking on them and choosing "Unmount".