# Confirm if entire drive is encrypted on Lubuntu 19.04

Tags: lubuntu, encryption, bootloader

As a noob to Linux I do not know if it is possible to **encrypt whole drive** with current **calamares installer**

I did a fresh install of Lubuntu with these options in calamares

```
erase disk +encrypt system
```

When rebooting it asks :

```
Welcome to GRUB! Attempting to decrypt master key...  
Enter passphrase for hd0
```

After decrypting I have only to log in as user

Normally we have to put password under Lubuntu logon

Is in this case the complete system encrypted ? 
Is the grub prompt normal ?

Here is the output of `lsblk`

```
sda                                8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                             8:1    0   300M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─sda2                             8:2    0 238,2G  0 part  
  └─luks-5fc-xx-xxx-xxxx-xxx
                                 253:0    0 238,2G  0 crypt /
sr0                               11:0    1   3,7M  0 rom   /media/
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Everything but `/boot/efi` is encrypted, yes.

This is indicated by the fact that `sda2` only holds a Luks volume (which is the encryption feature used by Ubuntu and many other Linux distros), which is in turn mounted on `/`.

The grub prompt is perfectly normal, given that the kernels reside on an encrypted partition, and `/boot/efi` only contains the bootloader itself. It has to ask for passphrase to read the kernel it has to load.

Comment: but when i open disk utility i see 2 free space areas . why are they created and why unencrypted ? i have added picture in question. can you take a look. and how about lvm .ist it better to use lvm with full disk encryption?

Comment: What free space to you see? The partitions adds up to the size of the disk. And LVM+LUKS is no more safe than only LUKS. LVM is a management layer, and doesn't really impact security. With your setup, you only have one partition for everything anyway, so LVM doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: i have edited question. look at foto. there are 2 small space areas created automatically . i dont think encrypted

Comment: There's a tiny free space in front and at the end, which is not used for anything nor encrypted.

Comment: in debian installer i always used entire disk and setup encrypted lvm to encrypt whole disk ...was my setup with calamares above as whole drive encryption ?

Comment: Yes, it is whole disk encryption. The unused space is there to align the boundaries of partitions to physical boundaries of the disk device.

Comment: are you sure boot also encrypted . why it is not under sda2 on lsblsk output?

Comment: `/boot` is encrypted, yes. It's part of `/`. From what you have posted you don't have a separate boot partition. You have a efi partition, which *has* to be unencrypted.

Comment: yes i have only one hdd partition as efi . you mean i have to decrypt boot ? i prefer to encrypt boot loader. i think it is or not ? just to be sure

Comment: You ***can't*** encrypt the bootloader. You can sign it, and use trusted boot. `/boot/efi` ***has*** to be unencrypted. You currently have no separate `/boot` partition.

Comment: i used g parted and i see lock symbol on boot/efi like in sda2 they have same lock symbol

Comment: I can't see the lock symbol  in your screenshot.

Comment: i will post hold on

Comment: I get what you ask. It's a key symbol. [See this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/473495/653515). In short: the partition is in use. It's not encrypted.

Comment: If you have further comments, I suggest you use [chat].